# pasar datos entre controladores mvc 4

Tags: mvc

Hola es mi primera pregunta en la pagina. tengo 2 controladores pero uno de ellos tiene una vista parcial y contiene una variables razor que me gustaria obtener su valor en la vista principal.

```
 Function Index() As ActionResult          
       Return View()
 End Function


Function Modal_Encuesta(codigo As String) As ActionResult
    ViewBag.idcodigo = codigo          
    Return PartialView()
End Function
```

como se observa paso una variable desde la vista index a la vista parcial pero como lo hago al revés?? pasar una variables razor al controlador Index y asi pasarela a la vista.

Comment: Indica también el lenguaje que estás utilizando para que los que tengan experiencia en ese lenguaje puedan ver esta pregunta de una manera mucho más rápida aunque por la forma en la que está el código diría que es Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso que muestras es el controlador pero falta el modelo y falta la vista.

El modelo que en este caso solo le hemos pusto un campo le definiriamos como:

```
Public Class ModeloIndex
  Public Property codigo As String
    ' aqui puedes añadir mas campos
End Class
```

La Vista que incluye un formulario con un campo

```
<div>
    @Using Html.BeginForm("Modal_Encuesta", "Home", New With {.ReturnUrl =      ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, New With {.class = "form-horizontal", .role  = "form"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.codigo, New With {.class = "form-control"})
        @<text>
            <input type="submit" value="Submitir" Class="btn btn-default" />
       </text>
    End Using
</div>
```

Y el controlador:

```
' Para llegar aquí con GET la url sería: http://... ~/Home/Index?codigo=Valor

 Function Index(m As ModeloIndex) As ActionResult
    'el valor de codigo viene y va en el modelo en m.codigo
    Return View(m)
 End Function
'
Function Modal_Encuesta(m As ModeloIndex) As ActionResult
    '
    '//ViewBag.idcodigo = m.codigo
    '//el ViewBag no sirve pues el valor ya llega a la vista en m
    '  
    '
    '//Tiene que existir una vista llamada Index.cshtml o Modal_Encuesta.cshtml 
    '//Falta decidir el resto de la estructura. Tal como está funciona con única Vista 
    Return PartialView("Index",m)
End Function
```

Creo que la pregunta es muy básica y la respuesta también lo es.
Es un esqueleto funcional para comenzar a armar formularios con MVC y Visual Basic

Espreo que esto te ayude.